# Android Switch Issue

Tags: java, android

I am currently using a switch in my Android application as sort of options in my settings class. However, when I change the state of the switch, from say false to true, and go back to the menu, and then go back to the settings activity, the state of the switch goes back to the default value. Is there a key line that basically saves the switch's state so that when a user returns to it, the state is the same? I don't think this question requires code, but if you think it's helpful, please let me know and I'll attach it. Thanks!

here is my activity code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.speedytext.Options" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Switch" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    android:text="Switch" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my java code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class Options extends ActionBarActivity {
private static Switch ding;
private Switch countdown;
public static boolean isDingChecked;
public static boolean isCountdownChecked;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);
    ding = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    ding.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // do something, the isChecked will be
            // true if the switch is in the On position
            isDingChecked = isChecked;
            System.out.println(isDingChecked);
            System.out.println(isDingChecked());
        }
    });
    countdown = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch2);
    countdown.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // do something, the isChecked will be
            // true if the switch is in the On position
            isCountdownChecked = isChecked;
            System.out.println(isCountDownChecked());
        }
    });
    isDingChecked = ding.isChecked();
    isCountdownChecked= countdown.isChecked();  

}

public static boolean isDingChecked()
{
    return isDingChecked;
}

public static boolean isCountDownChecked()
{
    return isCountdownChecked;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Some code is really helpful!

Comment: Yes we nned some code. Are You using a usually switch or a switchPreference? Only a switchPreference will hold it´s state, a usual Switch doesn´t.

Comment: you should put your switch state's into an arraylist then save them in either savedInstanceState or shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate()`, call [`setChecked()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#setChecked(boolean)) with your stored "is checked" value to set the default to whatever was stored previously.

Also, consider storing the settings to e.g. shared preferences. `static` variables do not persist over application relaunches and often make your code harder to maintain.

Comment: Yeah I have no idea why I didn't think about that...common sense. Thanks!

Comment: So what is the problem now?

Comment: I think it's because I didn't add the shared preferences part. If I go back to my menu activity and go back to this options activity, the state of the switch is lost. Let me try adding the shared preferences part! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Shared Preference Class

```
public class AppPreferences {

    private SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs;
    private Editor prefsEditor;

    public AppPreferences(Context context, String Preferncename) {
        this.appSharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Preferncename,
                Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
    }

    /****
     * 
     * getdata() get the value from the preference
     * 
     * */
    public String getData(String key) {
        return appSharedPrefs.getString(key, "");
    }

    /****
     * 
     * SaveData() save the value to the preference
     * 
     * */
    public void SaveData(String text, String Tag) {
        prefsEditor.putString(Tag, text);
        prefsEditor.commit();

    }


    public void clear()
    {

         prefsEditor.clear();
         prefsEditor.commit();
    }

}
```

Usage of Shared Preference in activity

```
AppPreferences appPref;

appPref = new AppPreferences(getApplicationContext(), "PREFS");
```

To save the state

When the state of the switch is changed save the state true or false to  a tag in shared preference

You can use this line to save the state

```
appPref.SaveData("Value", "Tag");
```

so it will be like this for checked state  `appPref.SaveData("true", "state");`

and  `appPref.SaveData("false", "state");` for unchecked state

in the oncreate of your activity get the value from the shared preference
using

```
appPref.getData("state");
if(appPref.getData("state").equals("true"))
{
//set ur switch button to checked state
}
else if(appPref.getData("state").equals("false"))
{
//set ur switch button to unchecked state
}
```

then check the result string for true or false 
and set the switch accordingly

Comment: should appPref.getData("state") be returning a boolean or string saying true or false?

Comment: string will be the return type thats y i compared the resultant string with equals method

Comment: oh my apologies didn't see the edit as i hadnt refreshed the page. let me try to see if it works!

Comment: So you mention that the last part should be in my oncreate. but what about the AppPreferences appPref;

appPref = new AppPreferences(getApplicationContext(), "PREFS"); and appPref.SaveData("Value", "Tag");. Isn't that also in teh same OnCreate?

Comment: ya you should initalize everything before you call appPref.getData("state") in your oncreate method

Comment: AppPreferences appPref;
appPref = new AppPreferences(getApplicationContext(), "PREFS");
if(appPref.getData("state").equals("true"))
{
//set ur switch button to checked state
}
else if(appPref.getData("state").equals("false"))
{
//set ur switch button to unchecked state
}
and in you listener chage the preference accordingly

Comment: Where would u set the switch accordingly? I am getting the boolean values correctly and am using them in my other activity, but whenever i return to my options activity, the defaults are back on false.